# Getting compatible version issue when running spring boot application however in pom there is only version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, resilience4j

Application is not starting however I only have added one version of resilience4j

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here are the logs:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configure.CircuitBreakerConfiguration.createCircuitBreakerRegistry(CircuitBreakerConfiguration.java:141)

The following method did not exist:

    io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(Ljava/util/Map;Lio/github/resilience4j/core/registry/RegistryEventConsumer;Lio/vavr/collection/Map;)Lio/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerRegistry;

The method's class, io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/Smit/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-circuitbreaker/1.1.0/resilience4j-circuitbreaker-1.1.0.jar!/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/Smit/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-circuitbreaker/1.1.0/resilience4j-circuitbreaker-1.1.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerRegistry


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.foosball</groupId>
    <artifactId>team</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <name>team</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <authentication>
                        <serverId>azure-auth</serverId>
                    </authentication>
                    <resourceGroup>maven-plugin</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>foosballteamserver</appName>
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>
                    <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
                    <deploymentType>ftp</deploymentType>
                    <stopAppDuringDeployment>true</stopAppDuringDeployment>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.jar</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>web.config</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Based on other posts in Stackoverflow, suggested to run `mvn dependency:tree | grep hibernate` command, it showing the below output:

```
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
```

Comment: Why are you defining spring-boot-starter-test with a different version than you parent defines? Does not make sense...

Comment: Fixed. However that still does not solve the resilience4j issue.

Comment: The resilience4j-spring-boot2 seemed to be defined by another transitive dependency. If you printout the whole tree you can see which one is using and check also the output ...furthermore I would strongly recommend to upgrade to most recent version of Spring Boot 2.2.X which is 2.2.5.RELEASE ...also you are defining jackson yourself which I recommend not to do....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Resilience4j` dependencies coming from the `spring-cloud-dependencies` pom.

Suggestion from issue [#864](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/864)

> Force `resilience4j-circuitbreaker` and `resilience4j-timelimiter` to version `1.3.1`

Try to change:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <resilience4j.version>1.3.1</resilience4j.version>
</properties>

...


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
    <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-timelimiter</artifactId>
    <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `spring-cloud-dependencies` then do not use resilience4j dependencies directly but instead you can use:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#configuring-resilience4j-circuit-breakers

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#bulkhead-properties-configuration

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfect for me and should be considered the right anwer to avoid setting specific versions for resilience4j.

Comment: FYI, Looks like updating the `io.github.resilience4j` dependency version to 1.7.0 also seems to be working fine with latest spring boot and spring cloud. So in old projects if code change is required to move away from `io.github.resilience4j` then check if this approach works. Make sure you add these dependencies before `spring-boot-dependencies` dependency in the pom file