# Actuator Class not found after 2.5.12 upgrade

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-sleuth

After upgrading to 2.5.12 from 2.3 I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration]

Including the dependency manually:

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
  <artifactid>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactid>
</dependency>
```

But still this issue exists. I use Java 11, spring cloud  2020.0.4, io.pivotal.spring.cloud 3.4.0, wavefront 2.2.1, spring-sleuth: 3.0.4.

Log:

```
2022-04-12 23:00:49.370 ERROR [traceId-,spanId-] [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
2022-04-13T11:30:54.31+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration]
2022-04-13T11:30:54.41+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334)
2022-04-13T11:30:54.51+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446)
2022-04-13T11:30:54.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369)
2022-04-13T11:30:54.71+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284)
2022-04-13T11:30:54.81+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193)
2022-04-13T11:30:54.91+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106)
2022-04-13T11:30:55.01+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81)
2022-04-13T11:30:55.11+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT app instance exceeded log rate limit (10 log-lines/sec) set by platform operator
2022-04-13T11:30:55.11+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285)
2022-04-13T11:30:55.21+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:103)
2022-04-13T11:30:55.31+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:82)
2022-04-13T11:30:55.41+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169)
2022-04-13T11:30:55.51+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150)
```

Pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wavefront</groupId>
            <artifactId>wavefront-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </dependency>

  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                        spring-boot-starter-actuator
                    </artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>
                                com.fasterxml.jackson.core
                            </groupId>
                            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>
                                com.fasterxml.jackson.core
                            </groupId>
                            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>
                                com.fasterxml.jackson.core
                            </groupId>
                            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>
                                spring-boot-autoconfigure
                            </artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
  </dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Zipkin Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wavefront</groupId>
        <artifactId>wavefront-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${wavefront.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have tried excluding conflicting dependency, adding manually, adding jar as external dependency. Cloud dependency is correctly configured. Why this is not loading `actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` class?

Comment: Spring Cloud and Spring Boot are heavily tied together regarding versions. You cannot just upgrade Spring Boot when using Spring Cloud, you have to upgrade Spring Cloud as well. Also make sure that you aren't mixing versions of jars from Spring (Boot) or another dependency.

Comment: I am struck here for the last 2 days, not sure of correct versions for spring boot 2.5.12, can you pls help me with any doc @M.Deinum pls I would be forever grateful

Comment: As stated Spring Boot and Spring Cloud are tightly coupled, so if you upgrade Boot yuou also need to upgrade cloud. If you didn't it won't work. Without seeing more of your application (the dependencies) this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: The table that shows Spring Boot and Spring Cloud compatible versions is on this page: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added my dependencies list, can you please help me why this thing is not working, i have changed my cloud version to 2020.0.5 as specified.I am seriously clueless of why this is occuring, Please help

Comment: For starters stop with all the exclusions and manually inclusions... That will only make things worse.

Comment: I faced the same problem when using latest spring boot version with `io.github.resilience4j` dependencies. Spring boot actuator dependency need to be added to pom file but that alone did not resolve the error so I also had to check the resilience4j dependencies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587334/getting-compatible-version-issue-when-running-spring-boot-application-however-in

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `resilience4j-spring-boot2` dependency. Update that to 1.7.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! After update `resilience4j-spring-boot2` from 1.4.0 to 1.7.1 issue has been resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Change your actuator dependency to this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>   
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

this works for me ..

Answer (score -2):

Please try this, its worked for us

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you want another version of micrometer use the proper mechanism and not an exclusion and added dependency.